# No internet through ethernet when another device connected to second ethernet port

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

I have a Dell Vostro 3900 with two ethernet ports. I use one to acquire data from a scientific equipment, and I'd like to use the second one for internet access. When the equipment is disconnected the internet works well, but when I plug it in there is no internet.
Windows doesn't see any problem.

Any hints on that?

I am using Windows 7 Professional. Upgrading Windows unfortunately is not an option.

Comment: Try: `route` (or via alias in GUI) ( https://superuser.com/questions/1048221/how-to-make-windows-send-specific-traffic-to-specific-ethernet-ports )

Comment: how are the ethernet ports configured? IP etc.? do both ports work with internet / equipment alone?