# How do I direct connect via Ethernet two Windows machines and keep their connection to the internet via WiFi?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, routing, ethernet

I have two Windows 10 laptops connected to the same router over WiFi. They can access the internet and can see each other in Explorer, file sharing works fine. I can ping one machine from the other one using its workgroup name or an IP address assigned by the router.

I want to be able to connect the laptops directly via Ethernet to speed up file sharing (sometimes I watch films from one laptop on the other one, and WiFi is not coping).

So far I used advice from [this](https://superuser.com/a/979118) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1048225) answers. Adding metrics to the Ethernet adapter did nothing. Setting it for WiFi changed the metric for the default route:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.11     10
```

I set up TCP/IPv4 settings on both laptops to use static IP addresses from the `10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0` space. I also added a route on both laptops that looks like it should've prioritised sending direct requests to `10.0.0.x` addresses via the Ethernet interface:

```
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        1
```

Still, I can't even ping one laptop from another using their `10.0.0.x` IP addresses. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider using Ethernet for all your uses.  Make sure wireless is WiFi 6 as that helps if you need to use Wireless

Comment: @John unfortunately that's not an option, and besides that single use case of sharing large files between the devices I'm pretty happy with wireless. I'd rather make the wired connection work

Comment: Note that I find transfer from PC-to router-to PC *much* slower than internet access. For example, though SpeedTest.net shows speeds of ~150 Mb/s over WiFi, and ~300 Mb/s *via* Ethernet, PC<->PC transfer *via* router is ~50 Mb/s, **at best**, and often bogs down. This might just be an issue for the setup here, though.

Comment: Pretty sure I got this working before - can you share the *actual* settings from your boxen? And I don't think you need the root when testing. Oh and windows blocks ping by default so check your firewall settings

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/299907/10165 this is what worked for me previously